# Python element-wise condition on numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, background-subtraction

I have two numpy ndarrays of the same shape.

```
A = [[12, 25, 6],
    [28, 52, 74]]
B = [[100, 2, 4],
    [2, 12, 14]]
```

My goal is to replace every element where there the value in B is <= 5 by 0 in A.
So my result should be :

```
# So C[0][0] = 12 because A[0][0] = 12 and B[0][0] >= 5
C = [[12, 0, 0],
    [0, 52, 74]]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? For context, this is to try to do some background substraction on images, and replace all background by black color.

Comment: `np.where(B>5, A, 0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
A = np.array([[12, 25, 6],[28, 52, 74]])
B = np.array([[100, 2, 4],[2, 12, 14]])

A = np.where(B <= 5, 0, A)
```

Output:

```
array([[12,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 52, 74]])
```

Comment: I think this is reasonable if you're creating a new array, but if you're going to clobber `A` then `A[B <= 5] = 0` seems neater. But then I find `np.where()` a bit unintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new array, I would do this:

```
C = A.copy()
C[B <= 5] = 0
```

It's a bit faster than `np.where()` on my machine anyway.

If you don't mind overwriting `A`, just do `A[B <= 5] = 0`.